# Retrieve dynamic value from DIV in Javascript to perform logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to both Java and HTML, I have a DIV that is populated with a dynamic value

```
    <div id=test>
    <span
     Test="TBinaryText"
     SITENAME="test site"
     OBJECTNAME="Temperature" 
     OBJECTTYPE="0" 
     INSTANCE="1" 
     DEVICE="1" 
     PROPERTYID="85" 
     INCLUDEUNITS="1" 
     ARRAYINDEX="-1"

    STYLE="position:absolute;top:73;left:188;height:16;width:34;z-index:43;overflow:hidden;font-        family:Arial;font-size:8pt;font-weight:700;font-style:normal;mask:0.1;">??? 
    </span>
    </div>
```

In the script I am storing the DIV as part of an Array (simplified for posting)

```
        var trial = [
          ['string',43,23,1,test]
                     ]
```

I want to use the value of the 'test' DIV to perform logic to determine the pin color of a marker on a map. If I alert the element of the array that contains the DIV it displays [Object] and not the content or value. I found and implemented a jQuery plugin to display the content, this works to perform the logic if the content of the DIV is a static number.

```
    var color =0;

    $(trial[4]).each(function(){color= $(this).output()}); 

     alert([color]); 

    if (color <5 ){ icon= pinImageBlue} else if (color>11) {icon=pinImageRed} else {icon= pinImageGreen}
```

However when I populate the DIV as above the alert will display the code and not the actual value. Currently to get the plugin to work I am using jQuery 1.3.2 as the newer versions error out. For the mapping i am using the google v3 API and the infobox API.

The plugin that allows the content of the DIV display is:

```
    (function($){
      $.fn.output=function(d){
        return (this.is(":text")) ? this.val(d) : this.html(d)
      }
    })(jQuery);
```

Is there a way to access the actual value of the code in the DIV and not the code itself?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Maybe you want text().

Comment: What code are you referring to when you say "When I populate the DIV as above, the alert will display 'the code'"?

Comment: In the first section of code. The site uses the properties in the DIVs span or in some circumstances a <Cust:TXT> to generate a dynamic value from a database. I am however not able to directly access the database value as it is not stored. Your answer below allows me to see the text value that is initally assigned but does not allow me to see the updated value. I am not sure if this can be corrected in the same area of the code or if there is a seperate approach that is neeeded. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you are looking for `.text()`

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eary9/1/) where I run your code and grab the value. I did it using jQuery 1.8.3

Comment: This does get close to what I am wanting in terms of stripping away the code, however when used on the live site it still only outputs the ??? or whatever static value is assigned. I need be able to get the live value which should, in this case be a numeric value. I was also not able to determine a way to use the value from the Array as I need to be able to loop through a number of different DIVs.

Comment: I kept looking at it and realized how to get it to read from the array by replacing the '#test span' with trial[4]. However I am still not able to get the live values. I am thinking that they may not be available yet. I use the same DIV to populate an InfoBox and it initally shows the static text for a split second before showing the live value. What would I need to do to update the color variable and thus recalculate for the Icon variable logic?

Comment: Are the values being added via PHP? If so, you may need to use livequery.